# Xpath find a node value matches in another node partially

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, mismatch, xpath-1.0

I have this XML:

```
<ref>
  <label>MCLaren, 1996</label>
  <year>1997</year>
</ref>
<ref>
  <label>Dhanvanth, 2016</label>
  <year>2016</year>
</ref>
<ref>
  <label>Darwin2 2001</label>
  <year>1997</year>
</ref>
```

I want to check year value "1997" against above label value "MCLaren, 1996" within respective  tag if year value mismatch with label need to show, answer expected in XPath

I have tried the below code:

```
/ref[descendant::label != descendant::year[contains(text(),'')]]
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understood what you want correctly, but the following XPath:

```
/root/ref[not(contains(descendant::label/text(), descendant::year/text()))]
```

returns all refs, where the year text is not contained in the label text

### Output

```
<ref>
  <label>MCLaren, 1996</label>
  <year>1997</year>
</ref>
<ref>
  <label>Darwin2 2001</label>
  <year>1997</year>
</ref>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I understand the concept now..